# Swift - UINavigationController bar color does not change programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a problem with changing the background color of my `UINavigationBar`. 
Here's what I tried so far:

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

The navigation bar does not change. Even setting the translucency to true has no effect at all.
I can change the tint color without any problems, but not the background color.

But if I change the color in the storyboard, it works fine!

Is there an option in the storyboard that I enabled/disabled by mistake? Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: use `barTintColor` property.

Comment: Swift 5 ios 13 Simple answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60856135/ios-13-4-sdk-update-navigation-bar-title-colour-is-set-to-black/60898211#60898211

Comment: Swift 5 IOS 13 Simple answer enjoy https://stackoverflow.com/a/60898211/6881070

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should set the navigation bar's `barTintColor` instead of `backgroundColor`. This should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Wow, so simple. Thanks for that. It works now. I will accept your answer asap

Comment: Setting `translucent = true` is still not working.. Any suggestions for me? Thank you

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure why translucency wouldn't be working. Is there definitely something behind the navigation bar to show through?

Comment: Yes I use a UITableView, and when I scroll down, the content is not behind the bar.

Comment: Are you using a `UITableViewController`, or a `UIViewController` and adding your own table? Perhaps check out some other questions on SO, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299481/ios-7-tableview-in-a-viewcontroller-and-navigationbar-blurred-effect

Comment: I'm using `UITableViewController`