# Is it possible to pin a UIView's top to the bottom of the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to position my UIView to be 20pt under the navigation bar, but when I set it relative to the view on the view controller it's still under the navigation bar at 20pt, and I don't want to hardcode it.

Is it possible to position it away from the navigation bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding contraint with TopLayoutGuide,

The main difference between TopLayoutGuide and self.view is, top layout guide starts with `bottom of status bar + bottom of navigation bar(if exist)`, but self.view always start from (0,0) coordinate in iOS 7 for translucent navigation bar.

So in your case you should try pinning from top layout guide.

[image: Top Layout Guide]
[image: self.view]

Comment: How would you do that programmatically?

Comment: UIViewController has provide category properties to access topLayoutGuide and bottomLayoutGuide

   interface UIViewController (UILayoutSupport)
    // These objects may be used as layout items in the NSLayoutConstraint API
    property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) id<UILayoutSupport> topLayoutGuide NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
    property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) id<UILayoutSupport> bottomLayoutGuide NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
    end

Take a look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19779200/1582217

Answer (score 6):

To do this programmatically use the `topLayoutGuide` of your view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive=true
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From iOS 11.0 programmatically you can use `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive=true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pin to the top safe area layout guide. Code if your are using SnapKit:

```
titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top).offset(20)
    make.leading.equalToSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score -5):

So your UIView sits within a UIViewController, correct?

When you define your initial inner UIView to that UIViewController, can you set its coordinates to be 20px off the top of the ViewController?

For example:

```
//
//  ViewControllerEx.swift
//

import UIKit

class ViewControllerExample: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var innerContainer = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height-20))

        self.view.addSubview(innerContainer)
    }  
}
```